# Gmail not forwarding imported emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, aol-mail

I currently have all emails from an AOL account being imported into a Gmail account, and that is working. Once a day it will do a mass import of new emails into Gmail from the AOL account. All imported e-mails are labeled with the AOL Gmail address.

I then setup various forwarding filters in the gmail account to forward certain imported emails to yet another email account. For example, if any email coming into the Gmail account have an attachment, forward it to the 3rd and final email account. This isn't working. No matter what filter I create, none of the imported e-mails from the AOL account will forward to the 3rd account.

I have looked into the issue ad nauseum, and I have yet to find a solution. The only related problem/solution I could find involved forwarding filters not working due to forwarding being enabled in the 'Forwarding and POP/IMAP' settings tab. Mine is not enabled, and the forwarding filters are not working.

I tested the filters by sending emails into the Gmail account directly, meeting the filter criteria, and they correctly forwarded the e-mails to the 3rd account. So the filters work on non-imported emails.

I tried calling Google, and they don't have support for Gmail, and they have zero technical support during COVID.

I just set my Gmail to forward all a copy of all incoming e-mail to another Gmail, to see if I can filter it in the 2nd Gmail. Not sure that makes a difference. I'll see tomorrow.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? It seems awfully hard to import and forward AOL mail. AOL doesn't have any forward filter options, sadly.

Comment: To add an update, the forward all incoming e-mails setting failed to forward any of the AOL e-mails to the other gmail account. It seems that I can't find any way for gmail to forward any imported e-mails, either by filter, or by forward all.

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't work for messages being retrieved by Gmail.  It only works for messages actually being received by Gmail.

You are importing messages, they are not being delivered to you, and as such will not be redirected by your incoming mail filter/rule.